# If PromotionType contains the word "Discount " but not "Discounted"

Tags: xml, xslt

I need help with XSLT. Sample XML is given below.

```
<offer>
    <Promotions>
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="5132">        
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Discount</PromotionType>        
            <PromotionLength>12</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>64</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="8400">        
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Discounted Price</PromotionType>
            <PromotionLength>6</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>0</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="5132">       
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Discount</PromotionType>
            <AssociatedCustomization>ATT-V5-HSIA-ULT-AI-VOIP-A</AssociatedCustomization>
            <PromotionLength>12</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>64</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="8400">        
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Discount + Reward Card or Amazon Prime</PromotionType>
            <PromotionLength>6</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>0</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>    
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="8400">        
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Discount + Reward Card or Amazon Prime</PromotionType>
            <PromotionLength>6</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>0</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="5132">        
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Discount or Device</PromotionType>        
            <PromotionLength>12</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>64</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="8400">        
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Discounted Price</PromotionType>
            <PromotionLength>6</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>0</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="9000">        
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Free Product</PromotionType>
            <PromotionLength>3</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>0</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>
        <Promotion sequenceNumber="9000">        
            <Amount>0</Amount>
            <PromotionType>Free Product</PromotionType>
            <PromotionLength>3</PromotionLength>
            <DiscountAmount>0</DiscountAmount>
            <RewardCardAmount>0</RewardCardAmount>
        </Promotion>
    </Promotions>
    <StandardFees>
       <Fee>140</Fee>
       <FeeTerm>Monthly</FeeTerm>
       <Description>No term commitment required.</Description>
       <RackRate>199</RackRate>
       <DiscountedFee>189</DiscountedFee>
       <DiscountTerm>12</DiscountTerm>
       <ContractTerm>24</ContractTerm>
    </StandardFees>    
    </offer>
```

If PromotionType contains the word "Discount" but not "Discounted" then I need to display Offer/StandardFees/DiscountedFee else Offer/StandardFees/Fee. Any help is highly appreciated. I need to do this in XSLT.

Comment: Please show your expected output. Also what version of XSLT?

Comment: More than the expected output and version, show your attempt at writing the XSL you need and describe what did not work. Stackoverflow is not a job replacement center where you get free programming, it is a place where you get assistance on programming issues your are having.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In addition to comments already given, have a look at [faq] and [ask], it will help you to write _questions that can be answered_.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept your looking for would be something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(PromotionType/text(),'Discount') and not(contains(PromotionType/text(),'Discounted'))">
    <xsl:value-of select="Offer/StandardFees/DiscountedFee"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="Offer/StandardFees/Fee"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

However,

1. You have to adept the paths based on the your context nodes
2. Did you notice, that `<offer>` is the only element name beginning with a small letter, while in your question you wrote it with a capital letter? XPath is case sensitive.